# Use Gradle composite build only locally and use dependencies in CI/CD

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I store library artifacts after compilation with Gradle in an internal Artifactory repository that is not accessible from the Internet. When I'm working offline or outside the company, I cannot access that repository.

One application ("web-application") that uses such libraries has configured the following settings in `build.gradle`:

```
...
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://artifactory.company.com"
    }
}
...
dependencies {
    compile(group: 'com.company', name: 'common-lib', version: '1.0.+', changing: true) 
}
...
dependencyManagement {
    }
    resolutionStrategy {
        cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
        cacheDynamicVersionsFor 0, 'seconds'
    }
}
```

This works fine for CI/CD and when I am in the office. It ensures the most recent *bugfix*-version of a library is used so not every project has to be touched whenever there is a bump of the *bugfix* counter.

To work offline, I came across the Composite Build feature of Gradle: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html

This way, I can check-out the code locally and add those settings:

**web-application/settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name='web-application'
includeBuild '../common-lib'
```

**common-lib/settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name='common-lib'
```

In addition, I have to remove the dependency in `web-application/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    /* compile(group: 'com.company', name: 'common-lib', version: '1.0.+', changing: true) */
}
```

Lastly, IntelliJ IDEA asks me whether to add a dependency on the module `common-lib`, which I accept. This works fine but then again, I can't commit the changes in `build.gradle` as this would break CI/CD pipelines that rely on checked-in libraries.

What is the correct way to make both scenarios work?

Comment: You could wrap the `includeBuild` in a conditional. For example, if you wanted to include it if the file was there like `if (file('../common-lib).exists())`.